# Wordpress Navbar has too much bottom padding and submenus are not centered on mobile screen width

Tags: html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I am currently moving my static HTML and CSS to a Wordpress theme and cannot get my Wordpress navbar working.

Here is a screenshot of what the full navbar currently looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBGkP.png

Here is a screenshot of the collapsed navbar: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vuvqe.png

Here is a jsfiddle of just my relevant HTML and CSS code... not sure how to make the terminal run the full navbar and include Wordpress: jsfiddle..net/9XLYE/

If anyone can help me get rid of the bottom padding in the full navbar and center the submenus in the collapsed version of the navbar, that would be greatly appreciated. Additionally, when I hover over the submenus on the website, the hover only highlights the text and not the black area around the text.

EDIT: edited to include the jsfiddle link. My bad!

FIX: I used the github Navwalker .php class to help me easily convert the navbar over.

Comment: Your jsfiddle link is missing...

Comment: That jsfiddle isn't going to help because it isn't going to show us what the menu is like on the collapsed version.

Answer (score 0):

I hope your problems are around your css. Check the padding / margin on your sub menus. And make the text align center / left depends on your layout. Provide hover background effect for the

tag. right now the text color change because of the  tag hover property. you must need to add hover css for your black colored part also.